# pass data from one view to another django

Tags: html, django, forms

I have two views in my app

Views.py

```
def selectwarehouse(request):
    z = Warehouse.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'packsapp/employee/selectwarehouse.html', {'z': z})

def warehouse_details(request):
    queryset = AllotmentDocket.objects.filter(send_from_warehouse = #dynamic(from the selectwarehouse.html))

    return render(request, 'packsapp/employee/allotwarehousedetails.html', {'query': queryset})
```

**selectwarehouse.html**

```
{% block content %}

<label>Select Warehouse<label>
    <select id="the-id">
        {% for i in z %}
        <option value="{{ i }}">{{ i }}</option>
        {% endfor %}
        <form method="post" novalidate>
            {% csrf_token %}
            <a href="{% url 'employee:warehouse_details' %}" class="btn btn-outline-secondary" role="button">Proceed</a>
            <a href="{% url 'employee:products_table' %}" class="btn btn-outline-secondary" role="button">Nevermind</a>
        </form>
    </select>
    {% endblock %}
```

URLS.py

```
    path('select-warehouse/', selectwarehouse, name='select_warehouse'),
    path('warehouse-details/', warehouse_details, name='warehouse_details'),
```

I want that when a person selects the "Warehouse" from the dropdown and clicks on **Proceed**, it should pass that value to `def warehouse_details` and pass the value to Allotment queryset. How Can I do that ?

Comment: You need to specify `action="url/to/warehouse_details/view"` in `<form ...>`. And your `<option>`s should be a part of a form

Comment: @YevhenKuzmovych Instead of href, I should direct it to warehouse_details View ?

Comment: Yes, I think so. Otherwise, the button just redirects you to `employee:warehouse_details` URL with `GET` instead of `POST` and without any information from `<option>`s.

Comment: @YevhenKuzmovych I am new to templates in django, Can you please show me how to do that ?

Comment: Your html form is inside out, and `<a/>` elements have no role in html form handling. It's important to understand HTML to use django. Read a few tutorials.   https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Forms/Your_first_HTML_form

Answer (score 0):

## MAKE Proceed as a hidden input

## Template

```
 {% block content %}

<label>Select Warehouse<label>
    <select id="the-id">
        {% for i in z %}
        <option value="{{ i }}">{{ i }}</option>
        <form method="post" novalidate>
            {% csrf_token %}
             <input type="hidden" name="object_id" value="{{ i.id }}">
  <input class="btn btn-outline-secondary" name="Proceed" type="submit" 
     value="Proceed"> 
            <a href="{% url 'employee:products_table' %}" class="btn btn-outline- 
        secondary" role="button">Nevermind</a>
        </form>
    {% endfor %}
    </select>
    {% endblock %}
```

## views.py

```
def selectwarehouse(request):
    z = Warehouse.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'packsapp/employee/selectwarehouse.html', {'z': z})

def warehouse_details(request):
    queryset = AllotmentDocket.objects.get(id=request.POST.get('object_id'))
    //Now to access the element in queryset write (queryset.'attribute name')
    return render(request, 'packsapp/employee/allotwarehousedetails.html', {'query': 
    queryset}
```

## Check if this works

### Try printing the queryset and see what is the output.

Comment: it won't , i just saw that 'endfor' is before the input , that is why it won't know what is 'i',take that 'endfor ' after </form>                 i have edited the code check now

Comment: you haven't have added any action in form tag, add it or else it won't work either way

Comment: or else give your repo i'll fix it out.

Comment: I can't give you the repo, sorry but Help me please add action to the proceed button